# Argumentos en argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, argparse

tengo una consulta básica de argparse pero no encuentro la respuesta en su documentación. Vereis, necesito pasar un argumento fijo a la linea de comandos, me explico. Por ejemplo:

```
python programa.py -t tiempo -false
```

En ese ejemplo -t es el valor que ha dado el usuario, pero -false quiero que sea un parametro que he creado yo y que signifique algo.
Estoy usando windows 10 y python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

De la misma manera que agregaste `-t tiempo`, con `parser.add_argument()`

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-false', help="hace algo", dest="varfalse", action="store_false")
args = parser.parse_args()
print("El valor de varfalse es {}".format(args.varfalse))
```

Se pueden hacer más cosas, es cosa de revisar la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method)